# I have stored user id and password in azure key vault and I need to retrieve those secrets in init container in kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have deployed an cluster in azure using kubeadm tool (manually) and it's up and running. I have stored a user id and password on external source i,e azure keyvault and I need to retrieve those secrets into init container and then initialize on main container , and can you please suggest me any idea. It's reaily helpfully to me.

Comment: Yeah, but in my scenario I need to retrieve the secrets into Init container first ..

Comment: Have you read these articles: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-integrate-kubernetes ?